# How can I dynamically build IN() SQL criteria values with a VBA function?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a **multi-select list box** on a form in Access 2010. I want to filter records in another list box based on what is selected in the primary list. Ideally I would like to do this in the query criteria.

Has anyone found a way to easily use a *VBA function* to populate the values for the `IN ()` statement? Ideally I am looking for something like this:

[image]

If I could get this to work, I could very easily create the VBA function to return a list of IDs.

**Other Approaches:**

Yes, I could load the selected values into a temporary table, and query them using `IN (SELECT MyColumn FROM tblTempValues)` but I don't really want to add another table just for this.

I could also use dynamic SQL, but I would prefer to keep it in the visual query designer for simplicity and maintainability going forward.

Allen Browne has a great example [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html), but I am wanting to avoid the dynamic SQL and keep things more simple if I can.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So...what's your question?  Have you read [ask]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have a user-defined function that returns a boolean in your `WHERE` condition, checking if an item is in the list:

Sample:

VBA part:

```vb
Public Function IsInList(myInt As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim arrList As Variant
    arrList = Array(1, 3, 4)
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In arrList
        If myInt = i Then
            IsInList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInList = False
End Function
```

SQL Part

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE IsInList(ID)
```

Of course, you can dynamically generate the list, and store it in a global variable, if wanted.

It isn't as efficient as an in clause, but if you don't want to use a temp table nor dynamic SQL, this is the only other way afaik